# Is there any way to using Cocoa in a C++ project?

Tags: c++, macos, cocoa

I want to use Cocoa APIs in C++ project instead of Carbon.

Is there any way to using Cocoa in a C++ project? Is it possible using Cocoa while developing a C++ project?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but you need to provide more information about exactly what you want to do. You can rename Objective-C .m files to .mm and then use C++. Alternatively, you can use the Qt framework and add OSX frameworks to the project. If that isn't what you want, can you be more specific with your question?

Answer (score 3):

My app uses a C++ library to provide its functionality and almost every source file is Objective-C++ (`.mm`).  There is no problem at all with this and it's working well.

I am careful to avoid using statements like `using namespace std;` and `using namespace MyLibrary;` in order to make it obvious (at least to me) where I am using parts of the Standard Library, my library or Cocoa runtime; for example:

```
std::string s = ...;
MyLibrary::MyObject o = ...;
NSString *nss = ...;
```